# unable to run a python script from localhost via ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I have my structure as :

```
playbooks_only 
    |
    |- read_replica_boto3.yml
    |- roles
         |
         |-read_replica_boto3
                 |-defaults
                 |-tasks-->> main.yml                      
                 |-files-->> - rds_read_replica_ops.py
                             - sample.yml
```

I need to run the rds_read_replica_ops.py , i wrote the following :

```
- name: Create a cross-region replica using boto3 script
  command:  python rds_read_replica_ops.py sample.yml
  args:
    chdir: '"{{ role_path }}"/files'
```

But this can't find the file and says:

```
sg: cannot change to directory '/home/blah/recovery/playbooks_only/"/home/blah/recovery/playbooks_only/roles/read_replica_boto3"/files': path does not exist

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Comment: Try changing this line: `chdir: '{{ role_path }}/files'`

Comment: what do u mean ? what i should be placing there?

Comment: Delete the double quotes `"` surrounding `{{ role_path }}`

Comment: oh cool okay , got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in this line:

```
    chdir: '"{{ role_path }}"/files'
```

You shouldn't surround variables with quotes. Instead, change the line to:

```
    chdir: '{{ role_path }}/files'
```

And that should work!

Comment: nice , just a question more. How should i wait for my python script to get it executed

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but this task sshould `cd` to the `files` directory, execute the file, and wait until it finishes

Comment: yes but then it doesn't pics the variable that i mapped from default/main.yml to files/sample.yml